# GNS3 can not ping from ethernet interface to serial interface

Tags: cisco, router, ethernet, ipv6, gns3

So I am doing a Lab for one of my classes involving ipv6 and routing using EIGRP. When I set-up the network and assign the router interfaces with IPV6 address I get an issue pinging the whole network. On the serial portion of the network, I can ping any port that has an IP assigned to it and using a serial connection and this is vice-versa with the other half of the network using ethernet for connectivity. I, unfortunately, can't ping an interface that is using ethernet or serial if ping from a router using opposite interface connection.

Network Design: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn5bY.jpg
[image]
Router Config

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1894 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 09:08:19 PST Sun Nov 1 2020
!
version 15.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
aqm-register-fnf
!
!
no aaa new-model
clock timezone PST -8 0
mmi polling-interval 60
no mmi auto-configure
no mmi pvc
mmi snmp-timeout 180
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
!
!
!
!
!
!


!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
ip cef
ipv6 unicast-routing
ipv6 cef
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!         
!
!
!
!
!
redundancy
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
! 
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 no ip address
 ipv6 address 2001:FACE:1111:1::1/64
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!         
interface Ethernet1/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Serial2/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial2/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial2/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!         
interface Serial2/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/3
 no ip address
 shutdown 
 serial restart-delay 0
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
 transport input none
!
!
end

Router 2
Building configuration...

*Nov  1 17:47:50.447: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console
Current configuration : 1951 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 09:47:50 PST Sun Nov 1 2020
!
version 15.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R2
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
aqm-register-fnf
!
!
no aaa new-model
clock timezone PST -8 0
mmi polling-interval 60
no mmi auto-configure
no mmi pvc
mmi snmp-timeout 180
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
!
!
!
!
!
!


!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
ip cef
ipv6 unicast-routing
ipv6 cef
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!         
!
!
!
!
!
redundancy
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
! 
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 no ip address
 ipv6 address 2001:FACE:1111:2::1/64
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 no ip address
 ipv6 address 2001:FACE:1111:1::2/64
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!         
interface Ethernet1/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Serial2/0
 no ip address
 ipv6 address 2001:FACE:1111:F001::1/64
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial2/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial2/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!         
interface Serial2/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/3
 no ip address
 shutdown 
 serial restart-delay 0
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
 transport input none
!
!
end
Router 3

Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1877 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 09:48:33 PST Sun Nov 1 2020
!
version 15.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R3
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
clock timezone PST -8 0
mmi polling-interval 60
no mmi auto-configure
no mmi pvc
mmi snmp-timeout 180
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
!
!
!
!
!
!


!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
ip cef
ipv6 unicast-routing
ipv6 cef
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!         
!
!
!
!
redundancy
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
! 
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 no ip address
 ipv6 address 2001:FACE:1111:1::3/64
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Serial2/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial2/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial2/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial2/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
 transport input none
!
!
end

Router 4
Building configuration...

*Nov  1 17:49:28.135: %SYS-5-CONFIG_I: Configured from console by console
Current configuration : 1934 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 09:49:28 PST Sun Nov 1 2020
!
version 15.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R4
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
clock timezone PST -8 0
mmi polling-interval 60
no mmi auto-configure
no mmi pvc
mmi snmp-timeout 180
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
!         
!         
!         
!         
!         
!


!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
ip cef
ipv6 unicast-routing
ipv6 cef
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
redundancy
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
! 
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 no ip address
 ipv6 address 2001:FACE:1111:3::1/64
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 no ip address
 shutdown 
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 no ip address
 ipv6 address 2001:FACE:1111:1::4/64
!
interface Ethernet1/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Serial2/0
 no ip address
 ipv6 address 2001:FACE:1111:F003::1/64
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial2/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial2/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial2/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
 transport input none
!
!
end

Router 5
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1937 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 09:13:12 PST Sun Nov 1 2020
!
version 15.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R5
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
clock timezone PST -8 0
mmi polling-interval 60
no mmi auto-configure
no mmi pvc
mmi snmp-timeout 180
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
!
!
!
!
!
!


!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
ip cef
ipv6 unicast-routing
ipv6 cef
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!         
!
!
!
!
redundancy
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
! 
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 no ip address
 ipv6 address 2001:FACE:1111:4::1/64
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Serial2/0
 no ip address
 ipv6 address 2001:FACE:1111:F001::2/64
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial2/1
 no ip address
 ipv6 address 2001:FACE:1111:F002::1/64
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial2/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial2/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
 transport input none
!
!
end


Router 6
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1937 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 09:32:48 PST Sun Nov 1 2020
!
version 15.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R6
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
clock timezone PST -8 0
mmi polling-interval 60
no mmi auto-configure
no mmi pvc
mmi snmp-timeout 180
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
!
!
!
!
!
!


!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
ip cef
ipv6 unicast-routing
ipv6 cef
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!         
!
!
!
!
redundancy
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
! 
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 no ip address
 ipv6 address 2001:FACE:1111:5::1/64
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Ethernet1/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Serial2/0
 no ip address
 ipv6 address 2001:FACE:1111:F003::2/64
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial2/1
 no ip address
 ipv6 address 2001:FACE:1111:F002::2/64
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial2/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial2/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
 transport input none
!
!
end
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

One big problem you seem to have with the serial interfaces is that you are not connecting DTE to DCE. You must set the clock rate on one side of the serial connection to set the interface as DCE, otherwise you are trying to connect DTE to DTE, and that does not work. You need to connect DTE to DCE.

For example, R2:

```
interface Serial2/0
 no ip address
 ipv6 address 2001:FACE:1111:F001::1/64
 serial restart-delay 0
!
```

connects to R5:

```
interface Serial2/0
 no ip address
 ipv6 address 2001:FACE:1111:F001::2/64
 serial restart-delay 0
!
```

but you do not set the clock rate on either side, and you must do that to set one side to DCE.

You could do something like R5:

```
interface Serial2/0
 clock rate 64000
```

You need to go through all your serial links and set one side to DCE by setting the clock rate.

---

> routing using EIGRP.

I do not find any EIGRP configuration at all in any of your configurations. You will need to set up a routing protocol, such as EIGRP, or you will need to configure static routes in order for all the networks to reach all the other networks. A router must be told how to reach a network, and there are three ways a router learns how to reach other networks:

1. A router inherently knows about directly connected networks.
2. A router can be configured with static routes
3. A router can dynamically learn routes through a routing protocol